# Images on Rails not showing up on my browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, view, asset-pipeline

I am trying to include an image in my web application but it is not showing up properly on my browser(localhost:3000). Have I set it up wrongly?

This is my view code:

```
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="‪assets/img/Lab Potion.png" alt="#" class="img-responsive">
                    <h2>random text</h2>
                    <p>random text</p>
                </div>
    </div>
```

I downloaded an image and saved it under:

```
-Desktop
 -rails_projects
  -project_name
   -app
    -assets
     -images
```

When I check in the images folder there is a file named `Lab Potion.png` and a bunch of random numbers inside(fingerprint?)

Why is the image not showing up?

Comment: You just need to have this `<img src="‪assets/Lab Potion.png" alt="#" class="img-responsive">`. Try to avoid white spaces in a file name too.

Comment: changing the file name to Lab_Potion.png also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= image_tag('Lab_Potion.png', :style => "z-index:19; position: relative; float: right;") %>` will work.  get rid of the space in the file name too, if not just for my sanity.

The random numbers are like a security feature and on each precompile the numbers end up changing. It's more complicated than that, but that is the gist.

And lastly, i doubt you have a `img` folder as well.